# Pushing and Incrementing the value in an array using a function

Tags: javascript

I am learning through an online course but the instructor computers seems to return the output as expected whereas my computer simply doesn't return me anything. also tried using online compilers

I am trying to make a "FizzBuzz" program.
Thanks for help anyways

```
var output = [];

var count = 1 ;

function fizzBuzz() {
output.push(count);
 count++;

console.log(output);


}
```

Comment: call fizzBuzz at the end of the function :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call fizzBuzz() at the end of the script :)
also keep in mind that after the execution you will have [ 1 ]
cause you're pushing the value before incrementing

the code:

```
var output = [];

var count = 1 ;

function fizzBuzz() {
output.push(count);
 count++;

console.log(output);


}
fizzBuzz()
```

Comment: so how can I increment before pushing? Do I have the reverse the position of count++ and output.push?

Comment: exactly, it should be:

count++;
output.push(count);